# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
in BreadCrumb (created by Connect(BreadCrumb))
in Connect(BreadCrumb) (at Dashboard.js:607)
in div (at Dashboard.js:606)
in Dashboard (created by Connect(Dashboard))
in Connect(Dashboard) (created by Form(Connect(Dashboard)))
```

I get this error sometimes.

Screenshot of error: https://screenpresso.com/=hjLdf

code in BreadCrumb.js:

```
class BreadCrumb extends Component {
   render() {
     const { title, subpath, subpath2 } = this.props;
     return (
        <h3 className="text-themecolor">{title}</h3>
     );
   }
}
```

code in dashboard.js:

```
  class Dashboard extends Component {
      render() {
          var title = "Dashboard", subpath = "Dashboard";
          return (
            <BreadCrumb title={title} subpath={subpath} />
          );
      }
  }
```

Comment: The code in your question is not the code giving rise to your error. [It works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/21qpvo807j).

Comment: Make sure `props.title` is a string and not an `Object`. You are passing it inside the <h3> and react doesn't know how to render it if its an Object. A good way to know that this is happening is also by adding a propType to Breadcrumb like this: ```BreadCrumb.propTypes = {
  title: propTypes.string
}``` it will display a warning in the console like: `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `title` of type `object` supplied to `BreadCrumb`, expected `string`.`

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are giving an object `{}` in the `{title}` a simple fix is doing this:

```
class BreadCrumb extends Component {

  render() {
    const { title, subpath, subpath2 } = this.props;
  return (
     <h3 className="text-themecolor">{title + ''}</h3>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will display [object Object] as a the title

Comment: I know, good point! I think it's better so you can visualize what you are actually sending. Instead of exploding the app with an error

Comment: Thanks @Vicente But I am passing a string in props from dashboard.js.
And trying to use the same in breadcrumb.js